# Regex for currency to float?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, floating-point, gsub

I'm working a RoR project, and I'm having some trouble writing a Regex to convert a string with a dollar amount to a clean number that can then be converted to a float. The dollar amount can come in any of the following formats: "$10.00", "$10", "10.00", "10".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use regex for this. Use the [Monetize gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/monetize):

```
Monetize.new(amount_in_cents)
```

Comment: Money.parse() is closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Found one! This works perfectly.

```
string.gsub(/[^0-9.]/, '')
```